# Double display of some data from the laravel database

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a strange problem, I went through the elements of the database with a foreach, but when I display in another page, instead of seeing me only one question from the database, I display two, from what is it? Is it running twice? https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjxfr.png

Route:

```
Route::get('/home', 'PostsController@viewPosts')->name('home');

Route::get('/viewUserQuestion/{post}', 'PostsController@viewUserQuestion')->name('viewQuestion');
```

Controller:

```
 public function viewPosts() {
    $posts = Post::latest()->get();
    return view('home', compact('posts'));
}

public function viewUserQuestion() {
    $posts = Post::latest()->get();
    return view('viewQuestion', compact('posts'));
}
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')

 <div class="card-body p-0">
@csrf
@foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="mailbox-read-info">
    <h5 align="center"> {{ $post->title }}</h5>
    <h6> From userID: {{ $post->user_id }}</h6>
    <span class="mailbox-read-time" align="center">Created at: {{ $post->created_at }}</span></h6>
</div>
 <div class="mailbox-read-message">
<p>{{ $post->content }}</p>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? I don't see any duplicate content in the image you've provided

Comment: They are not duplicate, they just have the same user id